# expression must have integral or unscoped enum type, with string vectors

Tags: c++, enums

So I am trying to make a program that will move all files of a certain type, from my downloads folder to the folder they are supposed to belong.

I have been researching this for awhile and finally have come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GetFileNamesInDirectory(string directory) {

    vector<string> files;
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(directory.c_str(), &data);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            files.push_back(data.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
    return files;
}

int main() {

    string *paths = new string[2];
    string line;
    ifstream pathFile("paths.txt");
    int i = 0;
    vector<string> rsFiles;
    string currentFile;
    int moveCheck;

    if (pathFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(pathFile, line)) {
            paths[i] = line.substr(line.find_first_of(" ")+1);
            i++;
        }
        pathFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    rsFiles = GetFileNamesInDirectory(paths[0]+"*.psarc");

    for (int j = 0; j < rsFiles.size(); j++) {

        currentFile = rsFiles[j];

        moveCheck = rename(paths[0].c_str() + currentFile.c_str(), paths[1].c_str() + currentFile.c_str());

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So when I go to move the files in rename(), I get an error with 'currentFile' saying "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". I am assuming this is because you can't index the way that I am, or something along those lines.

I am new to C++, but have other coding experience, and this is what makes sense to me.

Also, I know that I have taken code from other sources, but I do not intend on selling this or making it public, it is only for myself and my own personal use.

Comment: I think the close vote is unreasonable.  The question already shows more than enough context to show what the problem is.  (It's a pretty trivial problem, but we were all beginners once.)

Comment: Avoid using `new` and raw pointers, you could easily have written  `string paths[2];`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the way you concatenate two strings, to:

```
moveCheck = rename((paths[0] + currentFile).c_str(), (paths[1] + currentFile).c_str());
```

`c_str()` is taking the pointer to the buffer of characters inside each string, so adding two pointers doesn't make sense. Instead, you need to add the two strings, and then grab the data buffer from the concatenated string.

---

And another way to write this, from @Martin Bonner and @Nicky

```
std::string oldPath = paths[0] + currentFile; 
std::string newPath = paths[1] + currentFile; 
moveCheck = rename(oldPath.c_str(), newPath.c_str());
```

Comment: Also, I edited my answer now to make it clear that we are only using that pointer inside the call to `rename`

Comment: Yes, this is now well-defined.

Comment: You mean, you are not sure that this can be taught? At least 3 of us here have learned this already, so I guess it's teachable.

Comment: Good point @NickyC.  Better would be:  `std::string oldPath = paths[0] + currentFile; std::string newPath = paths[1]+currentFile; moveCheck = rename(oldPath.c_str(), newPath.c_str());` (with each statement on a separate line of course).

Comment: @AdiLevin I mean: The OP is new to C++, and the life time difference is quite subtle. Is it OK to offer this knowledge at this stage?

Comment: Ok. You're making sense :-). I edited my answer. Thanks!